# How to use select statements with in IF in T-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can somebody help me with the syntax of select with in a IF statement in SQL. I am getting an error when i use BEGIN and END with in IF.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE Proc1 @MonthSelection AS INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
      IF (@MonthSelection = 0)
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                YEAR([EventStartDate]) AS [Year]
                ,MONTH([EventStartDate]) AS [Month Number]
                ,DATENAME(MONTH,DateAdd( month ,MONTH([EventStartDate]), 0 ) - 1) AS [Month]
                ,COUNT([UserID]) AS [Total Number of Logins]
            FROM [Table1]
            WHERE eventtype ='login'
            GROUP BY YEAR([EventStartDate])
                    ,MONTH([EventStartDate])
            ORDER BY YEAR([EventStartDate])
                    ,MONTH([EventStartDate]
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT
                    YEAR([EventStartDate]) AS [Year]
                    ,MONTH([EventStartDate]) AS [Month Number]
                    ,DATENAME(MONTH,DateAdd( month ,MONTH([EventStartDate]), 0 ) - 1) AS [Month]
                    ,COUNT([UserID]) AS [Total Number of Logins]
                FROM [Table1]
                WHERE eventtype ='login'
                        AND MONTH([EventStartDate]) = @MonthSelection
                GROUP BY YEAR([EventStartDate])
                        ,MONTH([EventStartDate])
                ORDER BY YEAR([EventStartDate])
                        ,MONTH([EventStartDate]
        END
END
```

I did try doing with out Begin and ENd , but still i get an error. This piece of code is placed with in a stored proc.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

Comment: @user2919277 What line is generating the error?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'. Is the error i am getting

Comment: Remove Begin and End. Directly SELECT after IF/ELSE.

Comment: Not sure but this looks awkward to me `AS INT = 0
AS BEGIN`

Comment: @LynnCrumbling - the way is correct. Maybe you think about MySQL but this is T-SQL.

Comment: @i486 I did try it wont work.

Comment: Comment out all your code.  Start again with simpler queries, such as "select 1 record", so that you can isolate the syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis just before the `END` keyword.

This:

```
...

 ORDER BY YEAR([EventStartDate])
                        ,MONTH([EventStartDate]
        END
END
```

To:

```
...

 ORDER BY YEAR([EventStartDate])
                        ,MONTH([EventStartDate])
        END
END
```

Comment: O thanks you. That was a colon.? Thanks again. I was wondering why Begin and end dose not work in tsql